# Alternatives to Reed & Simon's book

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, soft-question, mathematical-physics

I'm looking for alternative references on functional analysis which can replace [Reed & Simon's](https://www.elsevier.com/books/i-functional-analysis/reed/978-0-08-057048-8) book. I'm a big fan of Reed & Simon, but I'd like to have other perspectives on some of its contents. One of great advantages of Reed & Simon is their vast number of applications, specially to physics, and I think this might be difficult to find, so you can consider applications to physics a "plus" but not essential. Topics I'm more interested in include: general theory of bounded and unbounded operators on Hilbert spaces, spectral theory for compact and self-adjoint operators (in particular, the functional calculus and Borel funcional calculus) and operator topologies (e.g. weak, weak* and strong operator topologies). Modern expositions are specially welcomed; I know, for example, that a more general approach to the functional calculus and Borel functional calculus can be given by means of $C^{*}$-algebras, where the operator algebras become just particular cases [this is not the approach on Reed & Simon, however].

**Note:** I know that many functional analysis books cover the listed topics, but my purpose is to find something compatible with Reed & Simon in terms of language, notation and structure. For instance, their approach is really self-contained and focused. Moreover, they seem to have a lot of results which are not only advanced material but also *useful* for applications in physics.

Comment: Is that for you to teach a course? if so, what is your audience?

Comment: @OliverDiaz it is not. I'd like to have it as my support material for research mainly.  And learn new additional material from another point of view.

Comment: All the topics you listed are contained in Rudin's book on functional analysis, although applications towards physics are not the intention there. Breziz book on functional analysis is also a great book, specially for a PDE oriented person; volume 4 of Simon's analysis books has classic and new material and plethora of references and historical facts, Peter Lax's functional analysis also contains an impressive amount of material. You may know these books already.

Comment: @OliverDiaz thanks for your suggestions. Indeed, I already know these books. Rudin helped me understand better locally convex spaces, but for some reason I don't love his book. Lax's book is also good, but as you mentioned it is too long and covers too many things. I'd like to have a more focused book which proves the essential but also discusses advanced results, not only introductory material.

Answer (score 3):

Specifically for spectral theory, you might be interested in "Quantum Theory for Mathematicians" by Brian C. Hall. The textbook covers quantum mechanics from a mathematical perspective, and it builds all of the spectral theory along the way. It comes equipped with proofs of various versions of the spectral theorems for both bounded and unbounded operators. It also contains the background on bounded and unbounded operators.

This book is more built around physics than Reed and Simon's text, and I wouldn't call it a functional analysis textbook. It is much more of along the lines of "let's carefully build the math that we need to do the physics," rather than "we're doing math, and here are some applications in physics." That might still fit within the scope of what you're looking for, and it's a very well-written book. It contains much more than just what I mentioned, as well (including background on Lie groups, Lie algebras, and group representations).

Also, it is a great reference for the aforementioned spectral theory.

Comment: @IamWill: A bit more pedestrian than Hall's book is [**Quantum Mechanics in Hilbert Space**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486453278) by Eduard Prugovečki ([review of the 1981 2nd edition by John Lee Challifour](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2975565)). I did a reading course out of parts of the 1st edition and found it rather dry and a bit too mathematically pedantic (the latter, however, is an advantage when self-studying), but it might be a useful complement to Hall's text (which looks nice, but I haven't yet seen a copy; however, I've jotted it down as a possibility the next time I buy books).

Answer (score 2):

Barry Simon was one of the leading experts in research on mathematical quantum mechanics, more precisely the operator theoretic side of it, and this immense expertise went into his books with Reed. This is just to say that you are setting a high bar if you want a book that includes advanced material with useful applications to physics.

If there is one researcher whose achievements in that period rival Simon's, it is probably Tosio Kato, and incidentally, he too wrote a book, *Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators*. Now I don't think I have come across someone who has used this book to study the basics of functional analysis, although it does contain a lot of the classical material of a first course in functional analysis. But since this does not seem to be the focus here, it might be just what you are looking for (and it actually has a broader range than the title suggests). As far as I remember, it does not go too much into the physical applications, but you will still find a lot of useful material if you want to study, say, Schrödinger operators.

Comment: Mao, thanks for your answer. In fact, Simon is one of the leading experts on mathematical physics and I set the bar too high, indeed. That's why I mentioned that I'd be happy to receive suggestions with no applications in physics at all. I believe that, apart from these applications, Reed & Simon's book is great because not only it covers a lot of material which *can* be applied to physics, but also it is very focused and organized. This is what I looking for with my question. (continues)

Comment: In other words, I'm looking for a great book on functional analysis, which do not necessarily contain applications in physics but have important theorems that *can* be used in such applications. As an example, it can discuss Stone's Theorem but not mention time evolution operators in QM. Also, a focused book means that it is not 1000 pages long and contains every possible subject in functional analysis; this makes a self-study and even consultation very hard sometimes.

Comment: In due time, I've skimmed the book "Applied Functional Analysis and applications to mathematical physics" by Eberhard Zeidler today. It seemed like a very good book too and a google search led me the impression that Zeidler was too a leading expert in QM back in his time. Do you have any opinion about him or his work?

Comment: @IamWill I don't think Zeidler did too much research in QM, but I might be wrong. I remember that I picked up his book on nonlinear functional analysis and tried to use it to self-study, but wasn't very convinced. But I cannot tell you what exactly I didn't like. I don't know the book you mentioned. Looking at the the references, they seem to come more from other corners of mathematical physics and not QM. In any case, I think Zeidler's research focus was mostly on nonlinear functional analysis, so his books might be a good complement to Reed and Simon.

Comment: In general, if you are looking for a book with content relevant to recent research, I find looking at the citations in mathscinet to be useful. Of course it tells you little about the accessibility of the book or how suitable it is for self-study.